# new column based on row and column conditions pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a sample data set:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {

 'ID': ['A','B','C','D','E'],
 'index_1':[2,0,2,-2,0],
 'index_2':[-2,-2,0,0,0],
 'index_3':[2,2,2,2,0],
 'index_4':[2,2,0,-2,0],
 'index_total':[2,2,2,2,2]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

it looks like:

```
   ID   index_1  index_2  index_3   index_4   index_total
0   A        2       -2        2        2            2
1   B        0       -2        2        2            2
2   C        2        0        2        0            2
3   D       -2        0        2       -2            2
4   E        0        0        0        0            2
```

i want to create a column named 'flag' based on following conditions **for each row**:

1. if any of the columns 'index_1', 'index_2', 'index_3', 'index_4' contains the value -2  **AND**  'index_total' = 2  then flag = 1
2. if columns 'index_1', 'index_2', 'index_3', 'index_4' only contain the value 0  **AND**  'index_total' = 2  then flag = 1
3. else: flag = 0

desired output:

```
    ID   index_1  index_2  index_3   index_4   index_total   flag
0    A        2       -2        2        2            2        1
1    B        0       -2        2        2            2        1
2    C        2        0        2        0            2        0
3    D       -2        0        2       -2            2        1
4    E        0        0        0        0            2        1
```

**my attempts (note i use loops for the index_1, index_2, index_3 and index_4 column names instead of writing them out because in my actual data set there are more than 70 index_ columns)**

**1st attempt:**

```
for colname in df.columns:
    if "index_" in colname:
        df[colname] = df[colname].astype(int)  
 #making sure the numbers are all integer for comparison
    if ((df[colname] == -2).any() and df['index_total']==2):
         df['flag'] = 1
  #this doesn't work , it's going by columns not rows
```

**2nd attempt:**

```
 for index, row in df.iterrows():    
    for colname in df.columns:
       if "index_" in colname:
           if( (df[colname][index] == -2).any() and df['index_total']==2 ):
                df['flag'] = 1
 # i stopped writing the other conditions because this one doesn't work
```

Comment: Discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419394/new-column-based-on-row-and-column-conditions-pandas-python/50419584?noredirect=1#comment87854900_50419584) you might want to read through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `any`, `all`, and boolean masking

(Comments inlined.)

```
# sub-select your column of interest
i = df.filter(regex=r'index_\d+')
# this is a common mask, we'll compute it once and use later
j = df['index_total'].eq(2)

m1 = i.eq(-2).any(1) & j   # first condition
m2 = i.eq(0).all(1) & j    # second condition
# compute the union of the masks and convert to int
df['flag'] = (m1 | m2).astype(int)
```

```
df
  ID  index_1  index_2  index_3  index_4  index_total  flag
0  A        2       -2        2        2            2     1
1  B        0       -2        2        2            2     1
2  C        2        0        2        0            2     0
3  D       -2        0        2       -2            2     1
4  E        0        0        0        0            2     1
```

Answer (score 2):

First condition:

```
df[cols].eq(-2).any(1) & df['index_total'].eq(2)

# (array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int64),)
```

Second condition:

```
df[cols].eq(0).all(1) & df['index_total'].eq(2)

# (array([4], dtype=int64),)
```

**`np.where`** to create new column:

```
c1 = df[cols].eq(-2).any(1) & df['index_total'].eq(2)
c2 = df[cols].eq(0).all(1) & df['index_total'].eq(2)

df['Flag'] = np.where(c1 | c2, 1, 0)

  ID  index_1  index_2  index_3  index_4  index_total       Flag
0  A        2       -2        2        2            2          1
1  B        0       -2        2        2            2          1
2  C        2        0        2        0            2          0
3  D       -2        0        2       -2            2          1
4  E        0        0        0        0            2          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a function that takes in the row and performs your logic:

Because you say you have many columns, we'll use `any` and `all` from the std lib. This assumes that `index_total` is the last column and the `ID` is the first column

```
def functo(row):
    if (any([i == -2 for i in row[1:-1]]) and row[-1] == 2):
        return 1
    elif (all(i == 0 for i in row[1:-1]) and row[-1] == 2):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

and apply it to your dataframe:

```
df['flag'] = df.apply(functo, axis=1)
```

We use `axis=1` to apply your function to rows instead of columns.

Also, a tip: I would avoid naming columns `index` because in pandas terminology, the index refers to a row.

Comment: No, looping here is the _last_ thing you should be doing with pandas.

Comment: Not sure I follow: Are you taking issue with the comprehensions?

Comment: I'm taking an issue with apply... which is nothing but a function called in a loop.

Comment: It just depends on the situation. For the extraordinary majority of use-cases, this will be fast enough. It has the advantage of being readible and _testable_: you can write unit tests for that function. I think most cases maintainable code trump performance here. No need to optimize that apply until you have some actual evidence that it affects your use case negatively. Looking at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html for example, if somehow ~100ms per row is too slow, there are options from there

Comment: Just because something is "fast enough", does not make it good practice, or something you should be recommending to those trying to learn pandas.  Just because driving 10 mph under the speed limit is usually "fast enough" to not get pulled over for driving too slowly, doesn't mean it's the right thing to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just cannot agree with that reasoning. If cython is needed, then write a function and cythonize it. Until then, you should stick to good practices and seek to vectorize where pandas lets you.

Comment: I think I disagree, @chrisz. Testable, readable, maintainable code that is fast enough is definitely good practice in a professional production system. Optimize for performance when you discover that performance is an issue. Otherwise, optimize for code you can maintain.  I've personally never experienced an issue using apply, and haven't heard it considered bad practice before. I'm open to learning something, however. But I suppose these comments aren't the right place for the debate.